# Recreate & replace recovery disk content Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language

Original new ASUS PC: Windows 10 Home Single Language, Spanish (incl. keyboard).
Changes intentionally made:

1. Replaced Spanish with Windows 10 Home Single Language, English. Method USB-boot media. Successful.
2. Upgraded to Windows 10 Professional, using bought key and upgrade process. Result: Success, but Windows 10 Professional is using a different key created online by MS. Activated OK.
3. The recovery partition still contains the Spanish Home version. How to update it so when needed it will install PRO English?
4. image shows disk allocation spaces:

4A) SSD with C: for small programs better on C: . SSD holds recovery partition. **Content to be replaced**.

4B) Hard disk with a partition for large programs and one for data.

An external Recovery is planned for later.

=====================================================

Question extended:
See new picture replacing the previous one. The top lines indicate 2 Recovery partitions, both 100 % free. I did not notice this before. Apparently there is no recovery data on the 2 partitions. (This subject is new to my level of experience, I better ask.) Why would Asus install 2 Recovery parts? How are these used when active (loaded)?
I intend to create a recovery of the SSD Windows section to guard the recently upgraded win10PRO English. Will wait for your recom´s. It seems to me the instructions from TENFORUM are not needed now.

---

The new picture mentioned does not show. Trying again to upload.[disk allocation with fill data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzYWU.jpg) Done, image shows during edit. It works via url. tks.

[[image: Disk partitions with text details on top area][1]]

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/106215-factory-recovery-create-custom-recovery-partition.html

Comment: Is there you want to recreate the recovery environment that presumably already works?

Comment: tenforums.com/tutorials/…  thanks, I ´ll change to tenforums, the info you provided is great.